# Upload file upload using angular8 and springboot

Tags: angular, file-upload

I don't understand the below code

```
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/upload/file', file, {
  reportProgress: true
});
```

I need clarity on the second argument which is a URL, at the moment I do not understand how it is supposed to map to server. I do realize that the above code doesn't use http, and. That's where I get lost. Please explain how server will see this request without URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code won't work if you don't specify the url. Typically springboot works in 8080 port in local machine. Following is a sample code of controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/upload")
public class ExampleClass{

    @PostMapping("/file")
    public String fileUpload(MultipartFile file){
        // upload file code
    }

}
```

`@RequestMapping("/upload")` is a parent mapping of whole controller, and `@PostMapping("/file")` is a child mapping. (It depends if you need `@PostMapping("/upload/file")` you can have it). This is the path you need to send the request to server from the front-end. So server will identity that this is the post request coming, so it will execute the method.

if you server port is running in 8080, you need to change to  `'localhost:8080/upload/file'` instead of `/upload/file`

Comment: But when I send the file, spring says Current request is not a multi part request... Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have a look https://bezkoder.com/angular-spring-boot-file-upload/

Comment: Uploaded successfully, it's cool now, I removed content type. Thanks a lot for your time. We'll i didn't follow Bezkoder, our codes are similar anyway...